# convert oracle Reference trigger to postgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql

How to convert below oracle trigger code to postgreSQL code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T1_TAB_AUR
AFTER UPDATE
OF
ISENABLED,
FREQTYPE,
FREQINTERVAL,
FREQSUBDAYTYPE,
FREQSUBDAYINTERVAL,
FREQRELATIVEINTERVAL,
FREQRECURRENCEFACTOR,
ACTIVESTARTDATE,
ACTIVESTARTTIME,
ACTIVEENDDATE,
ACTIVEENDTIME,
ACTIVITYID
ON T1_TAB REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
```

.......

I've tried like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_tab_aur AFTER UPDATE OF ISENABLED,FREQTYPE,FREQINTERVAL,FREQSUBDAYTYPE,FREQSUBDAYINTERVAL,FREQRELATIVEINTERVAL,
FREQRECURRENCEFACTOR,ACTIVESTARTDATE,ACTIVESTARTTIME,ACTIVEENDDATE,ACTIVEENDTIME,ACTIVITYID ON t1_tab 
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS NEWtb OLD TABLE AS OLDtb
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_tab_aur ();
```

But it is throwing this error

> ERROR: transition tables cannot be specified for triggers with column lists

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you have a **row level** trigger, so you want the same in in Postgres as well.

But for a row level trigger you can't specify the aliases for the `new` and `old` records - but as the are not renamed in Oracle anyway, just stick with the defaults:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_tab_aur 
  AFTER UPDATE OF ISENABLED,FREQTYPE,FREQINTERVAL,FREQSUBDAYTYPE,FREQSUBDAYINTERVAL,FREQRELATIVEINTERVAL,
                  FREQRECURRENCEFACTOR,ACTIVESTARTDATE,ACTIVESTARTTIME,ACTIVEENDDATE,ACTIVEENDTIME,ACTIVITYID 
  ON t1_tab 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE t1_tab_aur ();
```